# Click event is not being detected by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

(see the problem at http://theuseragent.com/nimmarket/test.html)

I've run into a bit of a strange issue. I basically am trying to get a click event recognized when I click on a magazine cover, however, for whatever reason, nothing happens!

I can't even write to the console or trigger a alert dialog.

So to explain the flow of things just in case it's not clear and to hopefully help jog some ideas..

a JSON file is being read by the app.js file and the magazine covers and the containing elements are being dynamically generated and attached to the div with the "middle" class.
It's being styled with inline css and the problematic JS is also being written inline.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Please summarise the code here, rather than asking people to trawl through your code for you. (You may well find the problem yourself while doing so...)

Comment: @lonesomeday I find that summarizing code sometimes helps me reveal the problem to myself - earlier I was trying to solve a JS issue and realized that I was misspelling an inline property after posting it in a question.

Comment: Good point, will remember next time. Was in a bit of a rush

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that you are loading the magazines via ajax but the click event you are binding is done on the initial load.  You either need to bind the click events when you are creating the magazines (in app.js - `init`) or use [jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  The jQuery delegate allows you to bind the event to a parent container (in this case `.middle`) and the event will fire when you click on the `.mag`

Comment: Or, since he's using jQuery 1.7.1, he can use the new ".on()" method.

Comment: Thanks Pointy.  I was unaware of that.

Comment: Thanks John! That WAS the issue. Didn't think of that for some reason.

Comment: Cool - the "on()" thing just unifies ".bind()" and ".delegate()" basically.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any onclick events being generated in app.js at all, just `a` tags with `href='#'`

Comment: The js attaching the click event was inline. Thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 0):

Not to state the obvious here, but there are no event handlers attached to the mag covers and the anchor tag reads "href=#".  Perhaps you should try to attach them or add href parameters.

EDIT:
Try using the child selector

```
>
```

like this

```
$(".middle > div.mag-box").click(function(){
```

Comment: He's got code to attach the event handlers already, but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Ah, there was so much code, I missed the attachment - sorry about that.  Check edit above.

Comment: The js attaching the click event was inline which is why you might have missed it. Thanks for taking a look though!